# How can I create a shared child between two tasks using TaskFlow Api?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-taskflow

My code look like this:

```
def etl():
    for item in ['FIRST','SECCOND','THIRD']:
        if item == 'a':
            requests = ['Data1','Data3']
        elif item == 'b':
            requests = ['Data1']

        for data_name in requests:
            @task(task_id=f'{item}_{data_name}_task_a')
            def taska():
                a,b = some_func
                vars_dict = {'a': a,
                             'b': b}
                return vars_dict

            @task(task_id=f'{account}_{data_name}_get_liveops_data')
            def taskb(vars_dict):
                some_other_func
                return True

            if data_name=='Data1':
                @task(task_id='last_task')
                def last_task(success):
                    dim_experiments.main()
                    return

            vars_dict = taska()
            success = taskb(vars_dict)
            last_task(success)


myc_dag = etl()
```

The dag looks like this:
[image]

When should look like this:
[image]

The goals is to have `last_task` dependent of `taska` and `taskb` except for that `taska` and `taskb` that download `Data3` Requests. I am not able to achieve it using `TaskFlow API`

Comment: Does the `last_task()` function need the output from the "success" task? As written it looks like the `taskb()` function returns True but the arg isn't used in the `last_task()` function but I understand this is just a snippet/example. Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @JoshFell Exactly it is a snippet but i explain you how should work.I send the output of `taskb()` to `last_task()` to create the dependency, but result it's not needed.

Each `task` except `last_task`is using previous task results, for example a `dict` with data downloaded, transformed, and cleaned. In `task_b` of of each thread data is copied from `s3` to `Redshift`. And in `last_task()` it should create a dim but results are not needed as they are stored in `Redshift` already. The issue is that only two threads can add data to that `dim` table, one of them is not valid yet to be in `dim`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parallel dependency is occurring because calling the `last_task()` TaskFlow function and setting the task dependency to it (implicitly via the TaskFlow API) is done within the same loop which calls the other tasks. Each call of a TaskFlow function will create a new task node. If `last_task` was pulled outside the loops and only the necessary dependencies were set inside the loops, you would achieve the desired structure.

Let's take a simplified version of your code as an example.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(dag_id="__example__", start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 1), schedule_interval=None)
def etl():
    @task(task_id="last_task")
    def last_task(some_input=None):
        ...

    for item in ["a", "b"]:

        @task
        def taska():
            return {"a": "A", "b": "B"}

        @task
        def taskb(input):
            ...

        success = taskb(taska())
        last_task(success)


myc_dag = etl()
```

In the DAG above, `taska()`, `taskb()`, and `last_task()` TaskFlow functions are all called and their task dependencies set within the loop. So, we see 2 parallel paths:

[image]

To have `last_task()` become a shared downstream task to both paths, we need to pull the call to `last_task()` (meaning that we only create a task node once) but keep the task dependency between `taskb()` and `last_task()` intact. This can be done with a small refactor of the example:

```py
@dag(dag_id="__example__", start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 1), schedule_interval=None)
def etl():
    @task(task_id="last_task")
    def last_task(some_input=None):
        ...

    last_task = last_task()

    for item in ["a", "b"]:
        @task
        def taska():
            return {"a": "A", "b": "B"}

        @task
        def taskb(input):
            ...

        success = taskb(taska())
        success >> last_task


myc_dag = etl()
```

Notice that the `last_task()` TaskFlow function is called *outside* of the loop creating the other tasks. This ensures that the `last_task()` task is only created once. The other change is to set the `last_task()` call to a variable and use this variable to then declare the task dependency to `taskb()` (similar to what you were doing with the `success` variable in your original code snippet). With these small changes we get 2 paths with a shared final task as `last_task()`:

[image]

Comment: that's awesome, I tried calling `last_task` outside of the loop but not storing it in a variable and defining the dependency using it. Great answer!